# php soap requires libxml

Tags: php, soap, libxml2

The php documentation said libxml is required for php soap (see [php soap](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.requirements.php)).

I don't how to "pass in" `--enable-libxml`.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: *This extension requires the libxml PHP extension. This means that passing in --enable-libxml is also required, **although this is implicitly accomplished because libxml is enabled by default.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to [recompile the php source](http://mattiasgeniar.be/2008/09/14/how-to-compile-and-install-php-extensions-from-source/) with the option --enable-libxml.

Note that by default libxml is enabled in any php installation unless explicitly disabled by adding --disable-libxml during compilation, are you sure libxml isn't enabled? Check `phpinfo()` output to be sure.

You'll probably find valuable info in the [libxml book at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php) too, especially the Installing/Configuration chapter.

Answer (score 2):

It is talking about when you configure php before you install it ...

```
cd /path/to/php
./configure --enable-libxml
```

You can also use yum or aptutide (apt-get) to install soap if you've installed php via one of those two ways.